# How to fix damaged NTFS partition?

Tags: linux, ntfs, partition-recovery, safely-remove-hardware

I have an external HDD with one **NTFS** partition. I wanted to transfer some files between PCs, so I have copied some files from Debian PC to the drive. After then as usual I have chosen safety remove before unplug the drive, then connected to Windows 7 PC which said "You have to format the drive before use", then connected to the Linux PC but it wrote errors only.
Firstly tried to repair it under Linux using the **ntfsfix (ntfstools 2.0.0-1)** program, but it said:

> "Mounting volume... Failed to open inode: Input/Output error.
>   FAILED  Attempting to correct errors...
>   Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
>   Reading $MFT... OK
>   Reading $MFTMirr... OK
>   Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
>   Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully
>   Setting required flags on partition...  Failed to read $Volume: Input/Output error.
>   FAILED
>   Error setting flags."

After tried to update the **ntfstools** to **1:2012.1.15AR.5-2.1**(testing) and got this message:

```
Mounting volume... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 2303  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 140  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xd8eb1fc2  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1001  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1277  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 160  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xd8eb1fc2  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1001  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
$MFT error: Invalid mft record for '$Bitmap'.  
FAILED  
Attempting to correct errors...   
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...  
Reading $MFT... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 2303  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 140  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xd8eb1fc2  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1001  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
OK  
Reading $MFTMirr... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1277  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 160  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xd8eb1fc2  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1001  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument  
OK  
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED  
$MFT error: Invalid mft record for $Bitmap.  
Cannot handle this yet. )-:
```

Then gave a try with chkdsk too on Windows, but it wrote:

> Unable to determinate volume version and state, chkdsk aborted.

Please help to find a solution, I have important data on the drive and I need them.